Is there any way to run a primary as a backup after the primary goes down without changing broker.xml?
I'm using 2 clustered ActiveMQ Artemis nodes in an HA configuration. When the primary is down, the backup has activated, and the primary is restarted I want the primary to act as a backup. Is this possible?
I am using ha-policy false scenario, but I need without using true scenario.
      <ha-policy>
         <shared-store>
             <primary>
                <failover-on-shutdown>false</failover-on-shutdown>
             </primary>
         </shared-store>
      </ha-policy>


I updated your question to use the proper configuration syntax and terminology. See more in the documentation.

When using a shared-store configuration the primary will automatically act as a backup if the configured backup broker is active and holding the lock on the shared journal. If you are not seeing this behavior then something is wrong either with your configuration or with your environment (e.g. your shared storage device doesn't support file locking).
